# Ext.On Ready () function not defined error in upload form . How to debug it?

Tags: django, extjs4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title> Upload Layer -  EtherSpat  </title>

<form action="."
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Upload a shp file:<br>
<input type="file" name="shp" size="40">
</p>

Upload a shx file:<br>
<input type="file" name="shx" size="40">
</p>

Upload a dbf file:<br>
<input type="file" name="prj" size="40">
</p>

Upload a dbf file:<br>
<input type="file" name="dbf" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../geodjango/geographic_admin/templates/ext-4.0.1
/ext-all.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../geodjango/geographic_admin/templates/ext-4.0.1
/ext-all.js"></script>


<script src="http://demo.geonode.org/media/static/script/OpenLayers.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{% autoescape off %}
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var form_target = "{% url maps.views.upload_layer %}";
  //  var xml_unsafe = /([^a-zA-Z\._])/g;
    var xml_safe = /([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[1-2]{1}[0-9]{3}_[a-zA-Z]+$)/g;
    var layer_name = new Ext.form.TextField({
      id: 'layer_name',
      fieldLabel: gettext('Name'),
      name: 'layer_name',
      emptyText: gettext('Unique name for layer.  Defaults to file name.'),
      validator: function(name) {
          if (name.search(xml_safe) == -1) {
              return gettext("The layer name must follow a pattern. Statename_city_year_datatype");
          } else {
              return true;
          }
      },
      allowBlank: false
    });

    var listeners = {
        "fileselected": function(cmp, value) {
            // remove the path from the filename - avoids C:/fakepath etc.
            cmp.setValue(value.split(/[/\\]/).pop());
        }
    };

    var base_file = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
        id: 'base_file',
        emptyText: gettext('Select a layer data file'),
        fieldLabel: gettext('File'),
        name: 'base_file',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: listeners
    });

    var dbf_file = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
        id: 'dbf_file',
        emptyText: gettext('Select a .dbf data file'),
        fieldLabel: gettext('DBF'),
        name: 'dbf_file',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: listeners
    });

    var shx_file = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
        id: 'shx_file',
        emptyText: gettext('Select a .shx data file'),
        fieldLabel: gettext('SHX'),
        name: 'shx_file',
        allowBlank: false,
        listeners: listeners
    });

    var prj_file = new Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField({
        id: 'prj_file',
        emptyText: gettext('Select a .prj data file (optional)'),
        fieldLabel: gettext('PRJ'),
        name: 'prj_file',
        allowBlank: true,
        listeners: listeners
    });

    var fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
        renderTo: 'upload_form',
        fileUpload: true,
        width: 500,
        frame: true,
        title: gettext('Upload Layer Data'),
        autoHeight: true,
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
        labelWidth: 50,
        defaults: {
            anchor: '95%',
            msgTarget: 'side'
        },
        items: [layer_name, base_file, dbf_file, shx_file, prj_file, {
            xtype: "hidden",
            name: "csrfmiddlewaretoken",
            value: "{{ csrf_token }}"
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: gettext('Upload'),
            handler: function(){
                if (fp.getForm().isValid()) {
                    fp.getForm().submit({
                        url: form_target,
                        waitMsg: gettext('Uploading your data...'),
                        success: function(fp, o) {
                            document.location = o.result.redirect_to;
                        },
                        failure: function(fp, o) {
                            error_message = '<ul>';
                            for (var i = 0; i < o.result.errors.length; i++) {
                                error_message += '<li>' + o.result.errors[i] + '</li>'
                            }
                            error_message += '</ul>'

                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                title: gettext("Error"),
                                msg: error_message,
                                minWidth: 200,
                                modal: true,
                                icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    });

    var disable_shapefile_inputs = function() {
        dbf_file.disable();
        dbf_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').hide();
        shx_file.disable();
        shx_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').hide();
        prj_file.disable();
        prj_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').hide();      
    };

    var enable_shapefile_inputs = function() {
        dbf_file.enable();
        dbf_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').show();
        shx_file.enable();
        shx_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').show();
        prj_file.enable();
        prj_file.el.parent('.x-form-item').show();
    };

    var check_shapefile = function() {
        var main_filename = base_file.getValue();
        if (main_filename.search(/\.shp$/i) != -1) {
            enable_shapefile_inputs();
        }
        else {
            disable_shapefile_inputs();
        }
    };

    base_file.addListener('fileselected', function(cmp, value) {
        check_shapefile();

        var main_filename = value.split(/[/\\]/).pop();
        var extension_index = main_filename.search(/\.\w+$/i);
        if (extension_index != -1 && layer_name.getValue() == "") {
            var cleaned = main_filename.substring(0, extension_index);
            cleaned = cleaned.replace(xml_safe, "_");
            layer_name.setValue(cleaned);
        }
    });
    disable_shapefile_inputs();
});
{% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

This is the code . I understand that I need to include ext-base.js , but there is no such file in the ext-4 package that I have downloaded . Is there a certain path I need to follow , as in the files need to be in a certain directory for it to work in Django ? This html file is in the templates folder and the ext-4 folder too is in the templates folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript and js files should be in your "media"  (Django <= 1.2) or "static" (Django 1.3) folders.

- **Django 1.3**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#basic-usage

  Put your js files in your app `static/js/` folder and use this in your template:

  `<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/foo.js">`
- **Django 1.2:** In your settings.py add:

  `MEDIA_URL = '/static/'`

  `BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

  `MEDIA_ROOT = '%s/static/' % BASE_DIR`

  Put your js files in your **project** `static/js/` folder and use this in your template:

  `<script src="{{MEDIA_URL}}js/foo.js">`

Be sure to configure your production web server properly as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-media-files